# How to not let a program end and repeat itself when a user chooses an option using a switch statement

Tags: c#, loops

Please note that I have fairly new to programming and C#. Kindly express your answer in a way that I understand.

I am trying to create a small text adventure in C# using the command window. I have a problem where I want two options/cases to be given to the user every single time they chose one of the options. I believe that I need to use a loop to make this possible, however, I am unsure how to implement it into my code.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my Battle Runners game!");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Chose an option from the list.");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Start Game");
        Console.WriteLine("2. About");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Credits and Information");

        String stringMenuOption = Console.ReadLine();
        int menuOption = Convert.ToInt32(stringMenuOption);

        switch (menuOption)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Loading the game...");
                //all game code goes here
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Battle Runners, developed by " + author +                 " is a text adventure that follows the life of a soldier in war.");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Author(s): " + author);
                Console.WriteLine("Version: " + version);
                Console.WriteLine("Date created: " + created);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You typed something incorrect!");
                break;
        }







    }
}
```

}

**I do not want the program to end when a user chooses one of the cases, or "options".** Every single time that the cases two and three are run at the user's request, I would like to have all of the cases (or "options") be repeated again to the user, instead of the program just ending. **When the first case is run, I would not like this to happen, but continue with the rest of my code.**

Comment: Okay, so you know that you need to use a loop.  What loops have you tried using, how have you tried using them, and what problem(s) have you had with those attempted solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap all that in a loop and exit the loop when the quit option is chosen.

```
int menuOption;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my Battle Runners game!");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Chose an option from the list.");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Start Game");
    Console.WriteLine("2. About");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Credits and Information");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Quit");

    String stringMenuOption = Console.ReadLine();
    menuOption = Convert.ToInt32(stringMenuOption);

    switch (menuOption)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Loading the game...");
            //all game code goes here
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Battle Runners, developed by " + author +                 " is a text adventure that follows the life of a soldier in war.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Author(s): " + author);
            Console.WriteLine("Version: " + version);
            Console.WriteLine("Date created: " + created);
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("You typed something incorrect!");
            break;
    }
} while (menuOption != 4);
```

Note: code is untested / uncompiled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works and I appreciate it. Could you please briefly explain what's going on, as I really don't understand it. Is the loop doing, "Keep replaying this block of code, *until* (while) menuOption equals 4"?

Comment: @Jake A "do" loop will always execute at least once.  Then at the end the "while" part checks that the selection was not 4.  As long as it isn't 4 it will go back to the top of the loop and run again.  Once the selection is 4, the condition in the "while" part will be false and the loop will exit.